how to use pgvector on a postgressql 16.1 database instance on AWS RDS?
As per AWS documentation, we can use the pgvectore extension in any postgresql database running 15 or higher.
But on my case it produces an error, when I give the command
CREATE EXTENSION pgvector;
I'm directly pasting the error:
postgres=> CREATE EXTENSION pgvector;
ERROR:  extension "pgvector" is not available
DETAIL:  Could not open extension control file "/rdsdbbin/postgres-16.1.R2/share/extension/pgvector.control": No such file or directory.
HINT:  The extension must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.

Additionally, I've run the following command:
SHOW rds.extensions;
It lists all the available extensions.
The vector extension is available there, but stil the same error on running the CREATE EXTENSION pgvector; command.

The name of the project is 'pgvector'. But the name of the extension is just 'vector'.

Not sure about AWS, but I had to use vector for my local installation:
CREATE EXTENSION vector;

